# TypeError: info() missing 1 required positional argument: 'state'

Tags: python

```
def info(state):
    if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
       while True:
           time.sleep(1)
           print('pos')
    else:
       pass
       

def gpas():
    s = Thread(target = info).start()
    

ui.checkBox_2.stateChanged.connect(gpas)
```

OUTPUT:

```
TypeError: info() missing 1 required positional argument: 'state'
```

Comment: The function `info` is defined to take an argument, but the way you're calling it, you're not giving it one

Answer (score 1):

It is YOUR responsibility to fetch the button state and pass that along to the thread.  The thread has no connection to Qt.

```
def info(state):
    if state:
       while True:
           time.sleep(1)
           print('pos')
    else:
       pass
       
def gpas():
    s = Thread(target = info, args=(ui.checkBox_2.isChecked(),)).start()
    
ui.checkBox_2.stateChanged.connect(gpas)
```